# How can one prevent accessing content directly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Using ASP MVC 4.5, how can one apply security measures in order to prevent users from accessing content directly?

Like for example preventing the access of images or other files stored on the web server just by entering their link.

Comment: Do you mean [Directory Browsing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731109(v=ws.10).aspx)?

Comment: can you post what web server are you using? Just an advice, You're web server is already unsecured because everybody can access it just by using the image links.

Comment: I am currently working locally. I need to prevent users from accessing images just by entering the link.

Comment: @Silvermind Yes, it has to do with direct browsing, however I need to implement it code wise and not via the IIS.

Comment: This is hard to answer without more details.  Why do you want to block users from accessing images?  If it's a strict security requirement, then you might consider something like inline base-64 encoded images.  But that may be overkill for your specific requirement.

Comment: I am implementing a photo sharing website where users buy photos from other users. Although I have already encrypted the photos I need to find a way to redirect the users once they try to hot-link one of the photos.

Comment: @JEPAAB So you just need authentication.  I would think you could use standard MVC authorization, no?  Make a separate controller for the images, with the appropriate "Authorize" attributes.  (mbeckish's answer is good, but seems more of an ASP.Net-style solution.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have produced the following **HTTPHandler** in order to prevent hotlinking.

*It seems to work on my project, however I do not certainly know if this is the best practice.*

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        //write your handler implementation here.

        //Http
        HttpRequest request = context.Request;
        HttpResponse response = context.Response;

        //Header - Properites
        int Index = -1;
        string[] Keys = request.Headers.AllKeys;
        List<string[]> Values = new List<string[]>();

        //Header - Loop to get key values
        for (int i = 0; i < Keys.Length; i++)
        {
            Values.Add(request.Headers.GetValues(i));
            //Check if property "Accept" exists
            if (Keys[i].CompareTo("Accept") == 0)
                Index = i;
        }

        //Check if URL and URL Referrer are null
        if (context.Request.Url != null && context.Request.UrlReferrer != null && Index >= 0)
        {
            //Check image types
            if (!context.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath.EndsWith(".bmp") ||
                !context.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath.EndsWith(".jpg") ||
                !context.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath.EndsWith(".jpeg") ||
                !context.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath.EndsWith(".png"))
            {

                //Check header "Accept"
                if (Values[Index][0].CompareTo("*/*") == 0)
                {
                    //Get bytes from file
                    byte[] MyBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(context.Request.PhysicalPath);
                    //new HttpContext(context.Request, context.Response).Request.MapPath(context.Request.RawUrl).ToString()

                    context.Response.OutputStream.Write(MyBytes, 0, MyBytes.Length);

                    context.Response.Flush();
                }
                else
                    //Redirect                
                    context.Response.Redirect("/Home");

            }
            else
                //Redirect                
                context.Response.Redirect("/Home");
        }
        else
            //Redirect                
            context.Response.Redirect("/Home");
    }
```

Also the **Web.config** was modified as follows:

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <!--My-->
        <add name="PhotoHandler-BMP" path="*.bmp" verb="GET" type="MVCWebApplication.Handlers.PhotoHandler" resourceType="File" />
        <add name="PhotoHandler-JPG" path="*.jpg" verb="GET" type="MVCWebApplication.Handlers.PhotoHandler" resourceType="File" />
        <add name="PhotoHandler-JPEG" path="*.jpeg" verb="GET" type="MVCWebApplication.Handlers.PhotoHandler" resourceType="File" />
        <add name="PhotoHandler-PNG" path="*.png" verb="GET" type="MVCWebApplication.Handlers.PhotoHandler" resourceType="File" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Feel free to comment on any improvements.

Comment: Is this the answer to your own question, or is this a new question?  If it is a new question, please make it a separate post.

Comment: However, I would like some feedback regarding this implementation.

Comment: To get opinions on best practices of your implementation, it would be more appropriate to post to [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 5):

1. Place your image in a non-web accessible folder.
2. Create a server side script (for example, an HttpHandler) that can read the image file and return its contents in the HTTP response.
3. In that script, perform your user validation to make sure the user has access to that file.
4. In the HTML, have the `src` attribute of the `img` tag point to your script.

The user can still directly type in the URL to your script to see the image.  But you can at least require that the user is logged into your site and is authorized to view the image.

Answer (score 1):

Use an authentication system such as [ASP .NET Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and require certain credentials to access the content.  Other than that, there really isn't a way.  If a user has a direct link and access to that area of your website, by nature of how web servers work, there isn't a way to stop it.

There are certain security measures you can take to help prevent users from getting a direct link though, a simple one would be disabling a right click.

Comment: I was looking into solutions regarding HttpHandlers, RouteHandlers and Web.config.

Something like the following:
[Http Handler](http://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/how-to-do-a-custom-secured-file-access-with-http-handler-and-mvc-framework)
[Web.config](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/thread/136467/how-to-prevent-direct-access-to-files-and-folders-in-asp-net.aspx)

Comment: You can use any fancy routing you like, but your route will still point directly to the file in question.  If the user has that route along with access to the location, they will be able to browse directly to it.  You could try and implement something fancy, such as authentication along with user specific files being copied into a temporary, uniquely named location, that get deleted after a certain amount of time; however, that's generally an extremely specific fix for things like download servers, it likely won't work well for site images.

Answer (score 0):

There is little you can do unless you want to bug your users. One possible (and widely used) thing could be checking your referrer (and make it be on your application), but that can easily be spoofed.

If security for this is something critical, the only thing that comes into mind is having everything downloaded through a script which would check for credentials (or any other security measure you might want), but there's not much else you can do.

If the browser has indeed downloaded something to the local machine, there's absolutely no way you can prevent that user to use that data (you can put some barriers, like avoiding right-clicking, etc., but all of them can be avoided in some way or another).

Comment: I was looking into solutions regarding HttpHandlers, RouteHandlers and Web.config.

Something like the following:
[Http Handler](http://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/how-to-do-a-custom-secured-file-access-with-http-handler-and-mvc-framework)
[Web.config](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/thread/136467/how-to-prevent-direct-access-to-files-and-folders-in-asp-net.aspx)